# why is this method returning null? (calling a set of strings from an array)

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm working on (what is to a beginner) a rather complex assignment. I think I've got the jist of it down, but I'm having trouble with it printing "null" after Monday-Sunday are entered into the dialog box. Also, the goal of the assignment is, later, for the user to enter a number 0-6 and then the corresponding weekday (from the String[] weekArray set in the method) is printed. I'm not really sure how to do this and my book doesn't seem to be showing me the way, but am I even going to be able to do that the way my code is set up? Thanks and best regards. Here's the code.

EDIT - there's an example in my book under returning an array from a method. I'm not sure if it's applicable to my assignment as they seem to have different goals, but here it is..

EDIT#2 - instructions for reference to what I'm doing.

EDIT#3 - my interpretation of the example for passing methods to arrays.

EDIT #4 - solved the issue. I was going about it the wrong way for much. The book's example wasn't much help. Thanks to those of you who replied. I deleted the homework assignment description in consideration of the professor (who probably wouldn't like his assignments on the internet next semester)

Excerpt of the code below... I was making this way more complicated than it was

```
public static String[] getWeek() {
    String[] weekArray = new String[7];
for (int i = 0; i < weekArray.length; i++) {
    weekArray[0] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 'Monday'. ");
    if (weekArray[0].compareTo("Monday") > 0) {
        weekArray[0] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 'Monday'. ");
```

Comment: Where is Friday? Rebbeca Black is going to fume....

Comment: haha well it wasn't actually in the homework assignment, i think he left it out by accident but i didn't include it at first because i thought he was doing it as some kind of trick for us to get around. once i got to the while loop after the array is passed from the method, i realized there's no way i could do what he wanted without "Friday". thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your branches have unreachable statements -

```
weekArray[5] = ...
while(weekArray[5].equalsIgnoreCase(null)) {
  // Cannot reach this point as equalsIgnoreCase(null) always returns false.
}
```

From [String#equalsIgnoreCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29):

> true **if the argument is not null** and the Strings are equal, ignoring case; false otherwise.

Emphasis mine.

EDIT: From your edit above you appear to be having trouble with populating an array. The rough idea is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // Just an example
  int[] values = new int[5];
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));

  populateArray(values);
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
}

private static void populateArray(int[] toBePopulated) {
  toBePopulated[0] = 42;
  toBePopulated[1] = 11;
  // Etc. Again, just an example.
}
```

This will print:

> `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`
>
> `[42, 11, 0, 0, 0]`

The idea is that what is passed to the method `populateArray` is a reference to the location of the array in memory. That means that you can manipulate the contents of the array, and the change will be reflected in `values` afterwards.

Comment: ahh thanks i thought that might be a problem. the only reason i set it to null, though, was without the while statements, the program stops running after I enter my first response. should I take out the while statement and find another way, or alter the while statement?

Comment: You're not setting it to null, you are *comparing* it to null. Setting it to null would look like `weekArray[5] = null;`. Also take note of your program flow: `return` will shortcut the rest of the `getWeek` method, and return to your `main` which will cause it to stop running after the first response.

Comment: @user1082706 Looks like you edited your comment, I'll take out my edit too!

Comment: I just edited it out because I was trying to paste in the code and it looked horrible. What i had was something like this.. while (weekArray[0].equalsIgnoreCase("y") statements; etc. it didn't work anyway..

Comment: @user1082706 If you're adding more code it's worth editing your question and adding the text **EDIT:** followed by the next part you are stuck on. This way you can format your code nicely.

Comment: I also tried a .compareTo statement. Should I be trying it from a totally different angle, do you think? My book is saying, under returning an array from a method, that it could look like this (example of returning a list with the numbers in opposite order) using a second array in a method)... I'll post the example code in the question like you suggest

Comment: i added the example in my book, can you have a look at it? it's pretty different from what i've been doing.

Comment: Your method signature `public static String getWeek(String[] weekArray)` takes an array as *input* and returns a String as *output*. The example in the book takes an array as input and returns an array as output.

Comment: I guess I'll just have to fix that then. I'm already rewriting it. I'm also going to post the instructions of the assignment here in a second. I appreciate your help by the way, sorry I need so much of it.

Comment: it's up there. if it's any more convenient for you, i have a yahoo or a gmail account you could add me on. gmail is jackxy2010@gmail.com and yahoo is sjis07@yahoo.com. Thanks

Comment: Check out my latest edit. Note that I'm trying not to give you a solution, instead simply guide you on the bits you are stuck on. Let us know if you get stuck on something else.

Comment: I also want you to know I'm not trying to get a solution from you either, I just had no idea what to do. I'm going to post an edit of what I had so you can at least see I was doing something, then I'm going to take a look at your code and try to figure out what you're saying. Thanks.

Comment: I just wanna say thanks again, I was making this way more complicated than it had to be. I got the program running. You did help me understand what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i got it right , but from a cursory look , seems you're mistaking the sunday part , guess it should be sth like :

```
if (weekArray[5].equalsIgnoreCase("Sunday")) // Note the "5"
```

Comment: well that was definitely an error on my part and thank you for catching it, it does not appear to be causing the null problem however.

Answer (score 0):

Your cheek for string being null is probably not what you want. If you indent the code it would be easier to see.

After formatting this is what you have

```
    while (weekArray[0].equalsIgnoreCase(null)) {
        if (weekArray[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Monday")) 
            return weekArray[0];
    }
```

So, if weekArray[0] is null, then you check if null equalsIgnoreCase("Monday"). This logic is not what you want.

After asking and checking all days you return null (at the end of the method). This si the null being printed.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still working on this. I'll let you know if I have any more questions. Not sure what to do here.